# Azure ASP.NET Backend for Android problems

Tags: android, asp.net, azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to create a .NET backend for my Android app using Azure.
I tried creating a ASP.NET web application based on the provided template for Mobile Services in Visual Studio.
Inside there is also a Seed to create a table and store some info in it.
I entered my credentials, Azure website URL, and Connection String.

However, when I publish the app, the table isn't created.
I tried to create the table myself, but it doesn't fill the table with the data.
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Azure Mobile Apps or Mobile Services?  You can't interchange the two.  Since you cannot create Mobile Services any more, make sure you are using the right template.

Aside from that, turning on debugging and looking at the SQL statements is a good idea.  Also, note that you need to send a query to the site before the table is created.

For info on turning on debugging, see: https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-19-asp-net-table-controllers/

For information on how Entity Framework initializes data, see [.NET Server SDK with Entity Framework](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#the-server-database-is-not-created-net-server-sdk-with-entity-framework) in the Mobile Apps wiki.

Comment: I'm using Mobile apps. I'm not so sure what to look for in the debugging. What do you mean by sending a query to the site?

Comment: Turn on Diagnostic logging: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/ - as well as the SQL logging that I described in the blog - you will see the actual SQL commands being sent to the DB.  Send a query to the site by requesting https://foo.azurewebsites.net/tables/yourtable?ZUMO-API-VERSION=2.0.0 in your browser - replace foo with your site name and yourtable with the name of your table.  You should get some JSON back and then you have done the query.